# Why is \footnote{} not making a footnote?

Tags: footnotes

It makes the raised number but there's nothing below it.

```
Qbert\footnote{Observe the popularity of foreign names}
```

The packages I'm using are:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: Did you try eliminating the packages in an MWE? Then you can discover by yourself what the problematic package is. Afterwards, you can ask a more specific question, showing that you have put some effort in your question.

Comment: Just a guess, but you should load the `gb4e` package last or almost last in the list of packages, since it messes with stuff that other packages sometimes use.  On constructing a minimal example see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Most likely your footnote is in a table or box of some kind. But please always make a complete document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 7):

```
\fbox{aaa\footnote{bbb}}
```

Does not work (and similarly any other kind of box command) the footnote mark will appear but the footnote text will not escape the box. Use

```
\fbox{aaa\footnotemark}\footnotetext{bbb}
```

so the footnote text is entered outside the box.

If you use multiple footnotes you also need to use the optional argument to foce the footnote texts to use the right number, variants of

```
\footnotetext[\numexpr\value{footnote}-1\relax]
```

depending on how many footnotes you have and how far you need to reset the counter.

Comment: Might worth to be added: `\footnotetext[{\numexpr\value{footnote}-1}]`