# How to get footnotes in parbox to show up at the bottom of the page?

Tags: footnotes

In the following example, the footnote simply does not appear anywhere. How can I get the footnote to show up at the bottom of the page?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent\parbox[t]{1\columnwidth}{%
Hello.\footnote{Here is a footnote.}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116039/117534

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes